# Error when executing sendRawTransaction on kovan testnet

Tags: raw-transaction

I am trying out execute sendRawTransaction on kovan testnet.

I'm following the instructions described in https://kovan.etherscan.io/apis#proxy. I'm using a POST request to send the request.

This is the data I'm trying to send as hex parameter

```
0x3ce49e670000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a76400000000000000000000000000007506c7bfed179254265d443856ef9bda19221cd7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000349f4957d8d5a7300000000000000000000000004dffea52b0b4b48c71385ae25de41ce6ad0dd5a7
```

After api call execution I'm getting the following response

```
{ 
    "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
    "error": { 
        "code": -32602, 
        "message": "Invalid RLP.", 
        "data": "RlpIncorrectListLen" 
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you find out the answer?

Comment: Nevermind, was looking for answer for something else with the same error, and I fixed it, thanks.